# How to expose internal control for styling?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The problem seems easy:
I have a `UserControl`, my control contains a `Button`.

`Button` elements can be styled. But I don't want to have style definitions in my control. My control doesn't even have XAML. All I want to set style like this in XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyControl">
    <Setter Property="ItsButton.Padding" Value="8" />
</Style>
```

It doesn't work that way. How does it work?
I know I can bind any internal control's properties to my `UserControl` dependency properties and it will work. However it's overkill to bind many properties, does it really require so much coding to do the simple thing, or is it an easier / quicker / simpler way?

BTW, it doesn't look like an overkill to you, imagine I have many internal controls like button, let's say `InputBox`es and such.

Here's the example control code:

```
class Installable : UserControl {

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(Installable),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnValueChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InstallButtonProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "InstallButton",
        typeof(Button),
        typeof(Installable),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InstallTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "InstallText",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(Installable),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnInstallTextChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Command",
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(Installable),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnCommandChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "CommandParameter",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(Installable),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnCommandParameterChanged));

    public object Value {
        get => GetValue(ValueProperty);
        set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
    }

    public Button InstallButton {
        get => (Button)GetValue(InstallButtonProperty);
        set => SetValue(InstallButtonProperty, value);
    }

    public string InstallText {
        get => (string)GetValue(InstallTextProperty);
        set => SetValue(InstallTextProperty, value);
    }

    public ICommand Command {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public object CommandParameter {
        get => GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
    }


    public Installable() {
        InstallButton = new Button();
        Content = Value ?? InstallButton;
        InstallText = "Install";
    }

    private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        var control = d as Installable;
        var value = e.NewValue;
        control.Content = value ?? control.InstallButton;
    }

    private static void OnInstallTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        var control = d as Installable;
        var text = e.NewValue as string;
        control.InstallButton.Content = text;
    }


    private static void OnCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        var control = d as Installable;
        var command = e.NewValue as ICommand;
        control.InstallButton.Command = command;
    }

    private static void OnCommandParameterChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        var control = d as Installable;
        var value = e.NewValue;
        control.InstallButton.CommandParameter = value;
    }

}
```

The control displays its `Value` when not null, `InstallButton` otherwise.
Like if value unset - it contains button, when value set - contains value. The control works like charm, but when I set the `Button` style in `MainWindow` XAML, it doesn't affect the button within my `UserControl`.

Maybe my `Button` could somehow inherit style from `Button` style defined in `MainWindow` XAML?

Comment: So you want to be able to let the consumer of the control style the button? If not, and if it's fixed, you could also set it in code.

Comment: The styling must be possible from within main style sheet XAML dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The control Style may define a default Button Style in its Resources, which will automatically be applied to all of the control's Button child elements.

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyControl">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Comment: Works as charm! And no need to expose the button.

Comment: @Harry It may even be sufficient to define a default Button Style in Application.Resources in App.xaml. Such a Style would automatically be applied to all Buttons in your application.

Comment: The encapsulation in a MyControl Style is better anyway, because you directly target only the Buttons inside the control. No unwanted side effects.